# Is this code vulnerable to dom based XSS?

Tags: xss, dom, jquery

Is this code vulnerable to DOM based XSS?

The application is using jQuery 3.3.1 and i noticed that Data is read from

`window.location.hash` and passed to `$()` via the following statements:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
var elem = $('#reports_nav_links .' + hash);
```

The link I have is something like `/graph#injection-point`

Every parameter I insert after the hash symbol gives the following error in browser console:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #reports_nav_links .injection-point
```

What payload could I use to trigger an alert box or execute any JS code? Is this code vulnerable or 100% safe?

Comment: @Arminius I don't think it's a duplicate of that question. Jquery version and statements are differents.

Comment: But especially the test site linked in the answer pretty clearly describes which versions are vulnerable and its example is directly transferrable to yours, isn't it?

Comment: The gist is that in newer versions of jQuery, a leading `#` guarantees that the string is always understood as a selector no matter what user-controlled data follows. (There may be interactions with additional libraries though.)

Comment: Further, modern browsers also encode hash fragment- making it unexploitable.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet that you pasted above is not vulnerable to the jQuery XSS vulnerability that you probably have in mind ([Bug #9521](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9521)) since it does not affect version `3.3.1`. The jQuery selector bug was fixed in version `1.7`.